# Duplicating SQL rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql

I have table which has columns for credit and debit account as rows of periods '1-12' and also a opening balance which should carry into each period.

Table

```
Account  |Period   |Credit |Debits    |Opening Balance
1000       1          100     0           50          
1000       2           0      100         50          
.          .           .      .            .          
.          .           .      .            .          
1001       1          50      0           100         
1002       1          40      0           100
```

But my problem here is can I duplicate or create 12 row with opening balance in each row for account 1001 and 1002??

Comment: you want to insert a blank row? I'm not sure I understand the question

Comment: In the above table i want to dynamically create a row say for Account ID 1001 (1001 2 0 0 100 and 1001 3 0 0 100 and so on)..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method.  It uses a join to a list of numbers to get all the combinations of periods and accounts.  It then uses a correlated subquery to choose the most recent value for the balance.

This version uses MySQL syntax.  The correlated subquery might use `select top 1` or `where rownum = 1` or something else depending on the database:

```
select t.account, n.n, coalesce(t.credit, 0) as credit,
       coalesce(t.debit, 0) as debit,
       (select balance
        from t t2
        where t2.account = t.account and
              t2.period <= t.period
        order by period desc
        limit 1
       ) as balance
from (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
      select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all
      select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12
     ) n left outer join
     t
     on t.period = n.n
```

Comment: Still I can get only one row even though left Outer join should return all the 12 rows?? Am I doing anything wrong??

Comment: Think the problem here is it creates 12 rows but assigns 'NULL' in account column,but I want the account also to be duplicated..regards